# IntelliJ 12 Android and Gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to use IntelliJ 12 (12.1.6 Ultimate) and Gradle to build Android projects? I can't find any information on doing so outside of Android Studio.

I can get my APK to build just fine, but IntelliJ doesn't seem to pick up the dependencies downloaded by Gradle. I know they're downloaded as I can see them in my cache folder.
[image: IntelliJ Gradle]

Switching from the `android` plugin to the `java` plugin works just fine.

Comment: Whoever voted to close as *asking to recommend a tool* clearly didn't read my question. At all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, as Android Studio is based on IntelliJ 13 (EAP).

Comment: Ouch. That makes sense now. Back to ant for me then. Thanks a lot!